# Interrupting controller parent action when a condition is satisfied in children method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, controller

I have several actions in my hotel_controller where I call an API to get back data. I created different services to keep my API calls outside my controller logic. For every API calls I have got some "general response errors" like `unauthorized` or `not found` for instance. As these errors are common to all API calls, I wanted to create a private method to deal with them in my hotel controller:

```
private
     def global_error_checking(response)
        if response.message == "Unauthorized"
          redirect_to unauthorized_path and return
        elsif response.message == "Not Found"
          redirect_to not_found_path and return
        else
        end
      end
```

Then in every method of my controller where it's needed I would call the global_error_checking method before checking for specific errors. For instance :

```
  def index
    service = Hotels::GetHotelListService.new( account_id: params[:account_id],
                                               user_email: session[:user_email],
                                               user_token: session[:user_token]
                                              )
    @response = service.call
    global_error_checking(@response)
    if @response["hotels"].blank?
      flash[:notice] = "You have not created any hotels yet !"
      redirect_to account_path(params[:account_id])
    else
      @hotels =  @response["hotels"]
      @account = @response["account"]
    end
  end
```

The problem is that after executing `global_error_checking`, the action of the controller goes on and does not stop even though a condition of `global_error_checking` is satisfied.

1) How can I stop the execution of the whole controller method if a condition inside `global_error_checking` is satisfied ?
2) Is there maybe a better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use return statement:
`return if global_error_checking` in your controller 
and `case` statement in private method with some changes:

```
private
  #returns true after redirecting if error message "Unauthorized" or "Not Found"
  def global_error_checking(response) 
    case response.message
    when "Unauthorized"
      redirect_to unauthorized_path and return true
    when "Not Found"
      redirect_to not_found_path and return true
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't name the parameter "response" since that's already being used by the controller.

The other thing I noticed is that you're accessing this "@response" in different ways which might be ok but it looks wrong. In your global_error_checking method you're accessing it's properties using dot syntax (response.message), however in your controller action you're accessing it as if it were a hash. Again, this might be ok depending on its data type.

If I were you, I would refactor this to look like:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @hotels = some_resource['hotels']
    @account = some_resource['account']
  end

  private
  def some_resource
    @_some_resource ||= begin
      service = Hotels::GetHotelListService.new({
        account_id: params[:account_id],
        user_email: session[:user_email],
        user_token: session[:user_token]
      })

      result = service.call

      if result['message'] == 'Unauthorized'
        redirect_to unauthorized_path and return
      elsif result['message'] == 'Not Found'
        redirect_to unauthorized_path and return
      else
        result
      end
    end
  end
end
```